# No icon in title bar after switching from WNDCLASS to WNDCLASSEX

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I just switched the game to use WNDCLASSEX so I can change the hIconSm, but for some reason there isn't an icon in the title bar anymore. The cursor and icon on the task bar and the icon for the EXE are all working fine though. Here is the main part of the window creation code:

```
 WNDCLASSEX wc;

 wc.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
 wc.cbClsExtra = 0;
 wc.cbWndExtra = 0;
 wc.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
 wc.lpfnWndProc = WinProc;
 wc.hInstance = hInstance;
 wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_ERROR);
 wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_ASTERISK);
 wc.hCursor = LoadCursorFromFile((LPCSTR)"FierceCursor.cur");
 wc.hbrBackground = (HBRUSH) (COLOR_WINDOW+1);
 wc.lpszClassName = "FierceWindow";

 RegisterClassEx(&wc);

 game->hinstance = hInstance;

 hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_CLIENTEDGE,
                          "FierceWindow", "Fierce",
                          WS_OVERLAPPED, 400, 100,
                          game->SCREEN_WIDTH, game->SCREEN_HEIGHT,
                          NULL, NULL, hInstance, NULL);
```

I've tried a few different settings for CreateWindowEx in hopes that maybe I used a style without an icon, but no luck. I'm using default icons right now to test.

Answer (score 0):

Won't compile:

```
error: cast from 'CHAR*' to 'WORD' loses precision
```

Thanks for the edit btw.

Edit - Got it to compile by changing it to:

```
    wc.hIcon = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(32513));
wc.hIconSm = LoadIcon(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(32513));
```

Comment: When I used WNDCLASS, RegisterClass(), and CreateWindow() it worked. I changed it so I could change the icon that's not showing up.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your window style. The icon appears only if you add WS_SYSMENU style.

> WS_OVERLAPPED|WS_SYSMENU